# ¿Por qué desaparece el cursor del JTextField al momento que se clickea dos veces sobre él? Adjunto video con pregunta

Tags: java, java-swing

El asunto es que hice un placeholder con el evento de raton(mouseClicked). Al momento que se clickea el JTextField se borra el mensaje escrito en él, pero ademas se borra el cursor. Les dejo un link a un video.[Link al video(click aqui)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbsnbO-Dp_Q&feature=youtu.be)

El codigo del JTextFiel es el siguiente:

```
    entradaNombre=new JTextField("Nombre del causante");
    entradaNombre.setLocation(margen2,280);
    entradaNombre.setSize(200,30);
    entradaNombre.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.PLAIN,12));
    entradaNombre.setEditable(false);
    entradaNombre.setBackground(Color.white);
    entradaNombre.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    entradaNombre.addMouseListener(this);
    add(entradaNombre);
```

El codigo en el metodo mouseClicked es:

```
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(ev.getSource()==entradaNombre && ev.getClickCount()==2) {

        entradaNombre.setText("");
        entradaNombre.setEditable(true);
        entradaNombre.setForeground(Color.black);
        entradaNombre.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.PLAIN,14));


    }
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Una simple busqueda en google  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561491/keep-caret-in-textarea-when-non-editable espero te sirva..

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me sirvio.
El problema es que no sé mucho ingles.